# SQL Syntax Error in JDBC when creating a Table with an ENUM

Tags: sql, derby

Success in creating the table without the ENUM, with it i get this exception
using Derby Database in Java

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
String sql = "CREATE TABLE Coupon (ID BIGINT, TITLE VARCHAR(100), START_DATE DATE, END_DATE DATE, AMOUNT INTEGER, "
+ " TYPE ENUM('Electronics','Health','Beauty','Restaurants','Leisure','Travel'),"
+ " MESSAGE VARCHAR(40), PRICE DOUBLE, IMAGE VARCHAR(100),PRIMARY KEY(ID))";
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

THE EXCEPTION:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "(" at line 1, column 113.
at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
at a.creatingTables.BuildCouponTable.main(BuildCouponTable.java:27)
 Caused by: ERROR 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "(" at line 1, column 113.
at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement.completeSqlca(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement.completeExecuteImmediate(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parseEXCSQLIMMreply(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readExecuteImmediate(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readExecuteImmediate(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatement.readExecuteImmediate_(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement.readExecuteImmediate(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement.flowExecute(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement.executeUpdateX(Unknown Source)
... 2 more
```

Comment: What's a TYPE ENUM ?

Comment: TYPE is an Identifier, ENUM explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type

Comment: You problem is that the database server does not like your sql. Try googling the correct syntax for your database vendor.

Comment: You should read the manual of the DBMS you are using, not some random article that isn't even directly to SQL. There is no such thing as an ENUM in Derby:  http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/ref/rrefsqlj24513.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this query adding `size` instead `type` like this:

```
 String sql = "CREATE TABLE Coupon (ID BIGINT, TITLE VARCHAR(100), START_DATE DATE, END_DATE DATE, AMOUNT INTEGER, "
 + " size ENUM('Electronics','Health','Beauty','Restaurants','Leisure','Travel'),"
 + " MESSAGE VARCHAR(40), PRICE DOUBLE, IMAGE VARCHAR(100),PRIMARY KEY(ID))";
```